# how to save any format of byte array content data to a file in winjs and save to local folder in windows tablet

Tags: javascript, arrays, windows-8.1, winjs

hi we are developing windows application using javascript , we want to download a file from json service which it returns some base-64 string we are converting that to byte array format like this and the binary data image has given below please give me some suggestion how to save that byte array data to a file and save it in local machine .thank you

```
WinJS.xhr({
    url: url, responseType: "arraybuffer",
    data: "{" + params + "}",

})
        .done(function complete(result) {
            var buffer = result.response;
            var dataview = new DataView(buffer);
            var ints = new Uint32Array(buffer.byteLength / 4);
            for (var i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
                ints[i] = dataview.getUint32(i * 4);
            }
            var data = ints;
```

we receive binary data like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
var folder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder;
    Debug.writeln(folder.path);
    folder.createFileAsync("page.html", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.replaceExisting).then(function (file) {
        return Windows.Storage.FileIO.writeTextAsync(file, r.response);
    }).then(function () {
        Debug.writeln("page saved");
    });
```