# How to save an array buffer to a local file on disk using javascript

Tags: javascript, arraybuffer

I'm practicing in programming with websocket, i'm building a java websocket server and want to send a binary data to websocket client, then client side can get that data through websocket and save it to a local file on disk, but i don't know what way using javascript to write an arraybuffer into a file.
My example code is shown below

```html
var ws = new WebSocket(URL);
ws.binaryType = "arraybuffer";
ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
     if (evt.data instanceOf ArrayBuffer) {
         // binary message is riecieved from server and i want to save it as a local file 
     
     }
};
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: try to post with a code that you have tried and faced problems with that

Comment: check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24996443/how-to-save-any-format-of-byte-array-content-data-to-a-file-in-winjs-and-save-to?rq=1

Comment: Ok! i will give an example code for describing my problem

Comment: Did the answer below solve it for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a textual/string representation that can be saved to and read from a file:

```
// returns String
function getArrayBufferString(arrayBuffer) {
  return new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer).toString()
}

// returns ArrayBuffer
function parseArrayBufferString(string) {
  return new Uint8Array(string.split(',')).buffer
}
```